# How to use a PayPal Hateoas link from json response in PHP?

Tags: php

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I am looking for a way to use (parse) a Hateoas link in json response, like this:

```
{  
  "links": [{
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }, {
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
    "rel": "parent_payment",
    "method": "GET"
  }]
}
```

to get those link for using in PHP, like this:

```
GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832
```

I have googled for hours to find a solution, but only got hits for how to create a Hateoas link.

I know how to convert json to array, but I don't know how to compose a usable link in PHP.

My goal is to use that link to retrieve detailed information from Paypal.

**Edit**
I saw I wasn't be clear enough.
For example, I want to get the url and the method from the json where 'rel' == 'self'.

Hopefully one of you guys can help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you want that href from the json?

Comment: @Arun Kumaresh Thank you for your reply. I want to parse the url and the corresponding method from the json to use that in a cURL request.

Answer (score 0):

After a number of trial and error I managed to find a solution myself.

It can be done using array_filter(array_map()) like this:

```
$key = 'rel';
$val = 'self';

$links_array = json_decode('{  
  "links": [{
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }, {
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
    "rel": "parent_payment",
    "method": "GET"
  }]
}');

$arr_filtered = array_filter(array_map(function($elem) use ($key, $val) {
  if ($elem[$key] == $val) { return $elem; }
}, $links_array['links']));

echo 'array filtered: ', var_dump($arr_filtered);
echo 'wanted array: ', var_dump($arr_filtered[0]);
```

This results in:

```
array(3) { ["href"]=> string(57) "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832" ["rel"]=> string(4) "self" ["method"]=> string(3) "GET" }
```

But in the end I chose for the old fashioned foreach loop, like so:

```
$link_arr = NULL;
foreach($links_array['links'] as $linkkey => $linkval) {
  if ($linkval[$key] == $val) {
    $link_arr = $linkval;
    break;
  }
}

echo 'link-arr: ',var_dump($link_arr);
```

Which gives me the same result.

Hereby my problem is solved.